# Django: access generic UpdateView with slug instead of pk

Tags: python, django

The code for using the pk is the following:

**views.py**

```
class CreatorUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Creator
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'location', 'country']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    # these two methods only give access to the users own profile but not the others (prevents url hacking)
    def user_passes_test(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            self.object = self.get_object()
            return self.object.user == request.user
        return False

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.user_passes_test(request):
            return redirect_to_login(request.get_full_path())
        return super(CreatorUpdate, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('creator/<int:pk>/update/', views.CreatorUpdate.as_view(), name='creator-update')
```

HTML snippet to call the URL:

```
<a href="{% url 'creator-update' user.pk %}">{{ user.get_username }}</a>
```

Now I would like to use a slug (username) instead of the pk to access the UpdateView. I can successfully pass the username to the URL:

```
<a href="{% url 'creator-update' user.get_username %}">{{ user.get_username }}</a>
```

but seem not to be able to match it in **urls.py**

```
path('creator/<slug:slug>/update/', views.CreatorUpdate.as_view(), name='creator-update')
```

with the same logic. I also tried to set a SlugField in my Creator model like this:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
class Creator(models.Model):
    ...
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.username)
        super(Creator, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    ...
```

And setting `slug_field = 'slug'` in the UpdateView also does not get it.

These modification result in a 404 error: raised by `catalog.views.CreatorUpdate: No creator found matching the query`

When adjusting the HTML part to `<a href="{% url 'creator-update' user.creator.slug %}">{{ user.get_username }}</a>` I get a `NoReverseMatch`error `Reverse for 'creator-update' with arguments '('',)' not found`.

What is the logic to use a slug to access a view?

Comment: if you put in your update url instead of pk  slug:slug  i think that it work

Comment: I guess you mean that you have a NoReverseMatch error? Could you post it?

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis I tried using the url ```path('creator/<slug:slug>/update/', views.CreatorUpdate.as_view(), name='creator-update')``` which gives me a 404 error raised by catalog.views.CreatorUpdate: No creator found matching the query

Comment: @guillermochamorro please find the error I receive in the comment above

Comment: So you have a list view with creator objects . so in your url try this <a href="{% url 'creator-update' object.slug %}">{{ user.get_username }}</a>. and in your url pattern leave slug:slug

Comment: @AaronScheib I'm not sure _I_ can help you, but it would be a good idea that you post the error in an edit of your question rather than the comments, so somebody may help.

Comment: The error is tha the user object has no attribute slug. The Creator model has the slug field.

Comment: @guillermochamorro thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis ```object.slug``` results in the same error. Wouldn't I be able to access the Creator object like ```user.creator.slug```? When doing this I get the NoReverseMatch error (Reverse for 'creator-update' with arguments '('',)' not found).

Comment: Create  a ListView of Creator Model then check if each creator object has a slug

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis that was it! The error was that I created the slug in my ```Creator```model from the field ```username```which is empty because the username is stored in the django default ```User``` model (not in my ```Creator```model). To solve it I created the slug using the ```user```field of the model ```Creator```. If you post your hint as answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that the user object has no attribute slug. The Creator model has the slug field. Create a ListView of Creator Model then check if each creator object has a slug.

Answer (score 1):

Correct **models.py**:

```
class Creator(models.Model):
    ...
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user)
        super(Creator, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```